# Comet JavaScript libraries that support multiple windows

Tags: javascript, ajax, comet

Are there any free [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) JavaScript libraries that allow multiple windows/tabs to reuse the same connection? In other words, when you open a second window, it detects that you have another window open under the same domain. Rather than open a new connection, it starts listening to the other window's connection. That way it can stay within the browser's per-domain connection limit.

[Lightstreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com/) seems to handle this well, but I'd prefer something open-source.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing you're going to find in the Open Source world is going to be the functionality build into [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/).

I'm sure in the future, you'll see more Open Source support for that kind of functionality...but for now you might have to hack something together.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly, because different browser windows/tabs don't know what connections are open in other browsers/tabs. The best you can do is either 1) wildcard a bunch of subdomains (the per-domain limit is per-subdomain too) or 2) use a cookie or some other form of persistent storage and fall back to short-polling, which is what the dojo framework does.